# Disable X-Powered-By in nestjs does not work

Tags: nestjs

I want to disable `X-Powered-By` in nestjs like the following, but it does not work.

main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const logger = new Logger('bootstrap') 
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  
    app.disable('X-Powered-By') // this line
    ...
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT
    await app.listen(PORT);
    logger.log(`Application is start on port : ${PORT}`)
  }
  
  bootstrap();
```

After disabling the `X-Powered-By` header, in the next requests, that `X-Powered-By` header still exists.

Where am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use:
`app.disable('x-powered-by')` - so all lower-case and it should work!

Answer (score 24):

If `app.disable('x-powered-by')` does not work, you can try/fix it with:

```
app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().disable('x-powered-by');
```

Comment: This works for me with Nest, Express and Typescript.

Comment: This is the one that worked with current version 8.x

Answer (score 12):

If you are using TypeScript and you get an error in your IDE saying `Property 'disable' does not exist on type 'INestApplication'`, then specify the app type in your `NestFactory.create` call.

Your code should look like below, and the error on the `app.disable` call will be gone.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule)

app.disable('x-powered-by')
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way is by adding [helmet](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/helmet) because not only remove `x-powered-by` but also help with other headers

Answer (score 2):

This way mine seems to work with **NestJs Version - 9**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import type { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
app.disable('x-powered-by', 'X-Powered-By');
```

[image]